# Why is this question a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

This [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/502/villages-and-hamlets-in-us-native-parlance) has recently been closed as duplicate. But I don't think its a duplicate.
Here the asker wants to know what would be called in American English a place like he defines. The [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/435/to-live-in-village-or-on-country) to which it is said to be duplicate wants to know meaning of living in village or living in country. This is true they share some common knowledge. But it cannot be said that it is exact duplicate. Rather this question can be **Related** Or **Referential**. Its like a question asks for "Difference between Gas and Liquid?" and the other one asking "What would you say, which state the matter is in: Solid, Gas or Liquid?"

Comment: I agree and have cast my reopen vote.

Comment: It's now reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not say they are duplicates.
The other question is actually asking if one should say "he is living in village" or "he is living on country." [One of the answers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/441/95) says *village* is not frequently used in USA, while [the other answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/446/95) says that only in the state of New York the word *village* is commonly used. Still, none of the answers explain the difference between *village*, and *hamlet*.

Even if one of the answers would *accidentally* explain what *hamlet* means, it sounds excessive to close the question as duplicate of a question titled "To live in village or on country?" and asking a completely different question.

Comment: False-positives  - claiming duplication where there is simply a vague relationship, is all to frequent.